# Query regarding the mathematical notation for convex hull

Tags: notation, computational-geometry

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), the convex hull can be mathematically designated by

$$\mathrm {Conv} (S)=\left\{\left.\sum _{i=1}^{|S|}\alpha _{i}x_{i}\ \right|(\forall i:\alpha _{i}\geq 0)\wedge \sum _{i=1}^{|S|}\alpha _{i}=1\right\}.$$

Can someone please tell me what $x_i$ is? According to wiki, it is supposed to be a point. Then shouldn't $x_i$ be a set of coordinates? Or is it a single value? If so, how is the single value obtained?

Comment: As the wiki entry itself states: "In a convex combination, each point $x_{i}$ in $S$ is assigned a weight or coefficient $\alpha _{i}$..."; so, the $\alpha_i$ are scalar coefficients for the $n$-dimensional points $x_i$.

Comment: $$S=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots x_{|S|}\}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a set of points $x_1, x_2,$ etc. In the plane, as a 3-point example (i.e., $S$ is a three-element set) you  might have
$$
x_1 = \pmatrix{1\\3}\\
x_2 = \pmatrix{2\\5}\\
x_3 = \pmatrix{-1\\4}
$$
The convex hull of those points (according to that formula) consists of all points that can be expressed in the form 
$$
0.2  \pmatrix{1\\3} + 0.3 \pmatrix{2\\5} + 0.5  \pmatrix{-1\\4}
$$
where the coefficients ($0.2, 0.3, 0.5$ in this example) must all be nonnegative (as these are) and must add up to one (as these do).